# Is there a way to prefetch the autogenerated key .push() will generate in Firebase Realtime DB?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to create a unique id for some of the objects I store in real time DB, but I would like the id to be in the object itself.  Is there a way two do this without without a 3 stop process, e.g. push the object, read the key, update the db's id field with the key?

In other words, if I want my DB to look like this:

```
properties: 
 -Mfq1Ek2geCnkol7EbeW: 
     id: "-Mfq1Ek2geCnkol7EbeW" 
     buyer: "ab3s3aga"
     seller: "b3skela" 
-Mq1Em5a3skfjal3EjkVDMN:  
     id:  "-Mq1Em5a3skfjal3EjkVDMN"
     buyer: "zk39xlal"
     seller:  "34kzla99dl"
```

Is there a way to do that without having to write twice to the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `push()` without arguments it's a pure client-side operation, that generates a new `DatabaseReference` object. You can get the `key` from this new object.

So (in JavaScript) you can get a new key with:

```
let newKey = ref.push().key;
```

Or you can keep the reference and the key like this:

```
let newRef = ref.push();
let newKey = newRef.key;
```

And then set a value to the new ref with:

```
newRef.set(...);
```

Comment: That's very helpful Frank, but not exactly clear how that works.  if the object i want to push is obj = {id : "-MfqE...", buyer: "abcde", seller: "qfqed"},  so I would do it with newRef = ref.push(); obj.id = newRef.key; newRef.set(obj); ?  And then obj will be written to the db with key of newRef.key?

Comment: Since you now have `newKey`, you can write that value as a property under `newRef` too, which is what you seemed to be asking for.